# Where can I find a list of building codes to put on a set of blueprints for a addition

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, architecture

Most architectural companies have a template of blueprints they reuse for every project.

As an owner-builder, I need to make these blueprints from scratch

On page 1, I have to list all applicable 2020 Residential Building codes for California

Where can I find a summary list of applicable building codes I can put on the first page

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

The same Building Department that you eventually submit your plans to.

In California other than very small single story additions, you find it more practical to contract a professional.

Any addition to second floor requires a complete structure upgrade.

Any addition in a hillside site requires a complete geology/soils report.

I would start from the planning department, they are trained to walk you through the process.

Comment: Ok that doesn't answer my question, I've built houses before. I know what Im doing. I just need the list summary of applicable building codes to put on paper, because I cannot put them all on paper

Comment: @Mich: Welcome to Engineering. One question: if you've built houses before, you should already have access to and knowledge of such codes. What did you do last time?

Answer (score 0):

Can pick sections from this text document and paste into plans

https://archive.org/stream/2019californiare00unse_0/2019californiare00unse_0_djvu.txt